# How to use two given inputs in a function and get the total

Tags: python, list

So I'm trying to create a function `totalcalories(recipes, tcal)` where `recipes` would refer to the ingredients that is going to be provided while `tcal` is the amount of calories that each ingredient contains...

I have figured out a way to find `tcal` from the given input but I have no idea how to extract the information from `recipes` into `tcal`

So like if the input is

```
`totalcalories(recipes = ["Pork Stew: Cabbage*5,Carrot*1, Fatty Pork*10",

"Green Salad1:Cabbage*10,Carrot*2,Pineapple*5",

"T-Bone: Carrot*2,Steak Meat*1"],

tcal = [["Cabbage:30", "Carrot:95", "Fatty Pork:2205",


 "Pineapple:40", "Steak Meat:215", "Rabbit Meat:225"])
```

And so I expect the output to return

```
"22295","690", "405"
```

So 22295 is the result of the recipe Pork Stew, which is Cabbage(30) from `tcal` times 5, which is 150, and 1 carrot, which is 95 and 10 Fatty Pork, which is 2205 each. Adding all three numbers give 22295.

The same principle applies for every recipe in `recipes`, where Green Salad would return 690 and T-bone 405...

What I'm trying to do is to write a function that will return the total calories like the examples I just provided...

Here is my attempt at it... which clearly doesn't work..

```
def totalcalories(recipes: list[str], tcal: list[str]):
    g = []
    for x in tcal:
        if x in recipes:
            g.append(x)
    return g
print(totalcalories(["T-Bone", "T-Bone", "Green Salad1"],["Pork Stew:Cabbage*5,Carrot*1,Fatty Pork*10",
"Green Salad1:Cabbage*10,Carrot*2,Pineapple*5",
"T-Bone:Carrot*2,Steak Meat*1"]))
```

What should I write to make my code work...

**Please write the code in the simplest way possible. I would like to take things really slow and understand what the code means so yea, please picture yourself teaching a beginner when you resolve my issue, so that I can also learn along**

Thank you!
`

Comment: Your input (esp. `recipes`) does not seem to be very friendly to a python beginner. It needs some potentially delicate parsing (maybe using `re` module). So I am afraid there might be a huge gap between what you want to achieve and "simplest way possible" code.

Comment: @j1-lee yep I agree it doesn't look very friendly at all. I've been trying to solve it for ages but I dont think I have learnt until 're' module yet, can u find an alternative and simpler way to do it?? It would really help :)

Comment: Given the moderate complexity of your data, I can't help wondering about its origin. Do you have control over the design? If yes, simplify it. If no, where does it come from? Or is this homework that you want Stackoverflow to solve for you?

Comment: @j1-lee the input isn't fixed and btw I do know abt dictionaries.. I tried to put the input into dictionaries but it didnt work at all.

Comment: @BrutusForcus I'm not the best at python rn so I decided to look up some practice problems for beginners, and I got stumped on this so yeaa

Comment: @BrutusForcus I do not have control over the design, the author of the file that consists these practice questions has done that already

Answer (score 0):

The input data structure is parseable (after all, there's always a way) but would be better if it was in the form of a dictionary. So, this code converts your structure into dictionaries and then goes on to show how much easier it is to process once they're in that form.

```
recipes = ["Pork Stew: Cabbage*5,Carrot*1, Fatty Pork*10",
           "Green Salad1:Cabbage*10,Carrot*2,Pineapple*5",
           "T-Bone: Carrot*2,Steak Meat*1"]
calories = ["Cabbage:30", "Carrot:95", "Fatty Pork:2205",
            "Pineapple:40", "Steak Meat:215", "Rabbit Meat:225"]

def cdict(): # convert calories list to dictionary
    d = dict()
    for e in calories:
        e_ = e.split(':')
        d[e_[0]] = int(e_[1])
    return d

def rdict(): # convert recipe list to dictionary
    d = dict()
    for r in recipes:
        i = dict()
        r_ = r.split(':')
        for c_ in r_[1].split(','):
            i_ = c_.split('*')
            i[i_[0].strip()] = int(i_[1])
        d[r_[0]] = i
    return d

recipes_d = rdict()
calories_d = cdict()

for k, v in recipes_d.items():
    tcal = 0
    for k_, v_ in v.items():
        tcal += calories_d[k_] * v_
    print(f'Recipe {k} has {tcal} calories')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define 2 patterns: one to capture the name of the recipe, the second to capture each single ingredient in the recipe itself.

```
pattern_recipe = re.compile(r'([^\:]*):.*')
pattern_ingredients = re.compile(r'([^\*\:,]*)\*(\d*),?', re.DOTALL)
```

Now, process each line of your `totalcalories_recipes` list create a `dictionary` which is keyed with the name of the recipe and element the list of ingredients with calories:

```
recipes_dict = {pattern_recipe.findall(x)[0]:
                   [(ingredient.strip(), int(calories)) for ingredient, calories in pattern_ingredients.findall(x)] 
                for x in totalcalories_recipes}
```

To be clear, the nested list comprehension cleans `ingredient` name, stripping spaces, and casts `calories` into `int`.

At this point, your `recipes_dict` should look as follows:

```
 {'Pork Stew': [('Cabbage', 5), ('Carrot', 1), ('Fatty Pork', 10)], 'Green Salad1': [('Cabbage', 10), ('Carrot', 2), ('Pineapple', 5)], 'T-Bone': [('Carrot', 2), ('Steak Meat', 1)]}
```

In a similar fashion, you can get a dictionary from your tcal list:

```
tcal_dict = {x[0]:int(x[1]) for x in [re.findall("([^\:]*)\:(\d+)", x)[0] for x in tcal]}
```

Now you are in business! Looping through each recipe in `recipes_dict`, you can calculate the calories by recipe:

```
{recipe[0]:sum([ingredient[1] * tcal_dict[ingredient[0]] for ingredient in recipe[1]]) for recipe in recipes_dict.items()}
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'Pork Stew': 22295, 'Green Salad1': 690, 'T-Bone': 405}
```